# Manipulating string in android

Tags: android, string

In My project need to manipulate string

Example 
 Need This Type of string

String Message= "NJJJBJHBHKKNJBJHVHGCGFXFGXFGXFfdfd";
String b="fjhvdshfvdghfgvdgh";

i need  if String  b's length is less than message then provide a space 
OR
If b's length is grater than message then find sub String

Please help me how i can set white space in String

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make white space strings with specific **length**:

```
new String(new char[length]).replace('\0', ' ');
```